# Read CSV file using tf.data is very slow, use tfrecords instead?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I have a lot of CSV files with each record containing ~6000 columns. The first column is the label and the remaining columns should be treated as a feature vector. I'm new to Tensorflow and I can't figure out how to read the data into a  Tensorflow `Dataset` with the desired format. I have the following code running currently:

```
DEFAULTS = []
n_features = 6170
for i in range(n_features+1):
  DEFAULTS.append([0.0])

def parse_csv(line):
    # line = line.replace('"', '')
    columns = tf.decode_csv(line, record_defaults=DEFAULTS)  # take a line at a time
    features = {'label': columns[-1], 'x': tf.stack(columns[:-1])}  # create a dictionary out of the features
    labels = features.pop('label')  # define the label

    return features, labels


def train_input_fn(data_file=sample_csv_file, batch_size=128):
    """Generate an input function for the Estimator."""
    # Extract lines from input files using the Dataset API.
    dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset(data_file)
    dataset = dataset.map(parse_csv)
    dataset = dataset.shuffle(10000).repeat().batch(batch_size)
    return dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
```

Each CSV file has ~10K records. I've tried to do a sample eval on `train_input_fn` as `labels = train_input_fn()[1].eval(session=sess)`. This gets 128 labels, but it's taking around **2 minutes**.

Am I using some redundant operations or is there any better way to do this?

PS: I have the original data in Spark Dataframe. Hence, I can use TFRecords as well if that can make things faster.

Comment: Let me know if my answer, addressed your problem. thanks

Comment: you even can create .tfrecord file yourself (if you don't have it) - like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41402332/tensorflow-create-a-tfrecords-file-from-csv) -- but for speed - test needed: "[There](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/tfrecord) is no need to convert existing code to use TFRecords, unless you are using _tf.data_ and reading data is still the bottleneck to training" & _tf.data_ is reported to really simplify dealing with collections of files, otherwise just _from_tensor_slices(dict(df))_ is enough for csv_data, also for encoded images data TFrecord used

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are doing it right. But a faster way is to use `TFRecords` as shown in the following steps:

1. Use `tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter`:
   --
   To read the csv file and write it as a tfrecord file as shown here:[Tensorflow create a tfrecords file from csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41402332/tensorflow-create-a-tfrecords-file-from-csv).
2. Reading from the tfrecord :
   --

   ```
   def _parse_function(proto):
      f = {
          "features": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], tf.float32, default_value=0.0, allow_missing=True),
          "label": tf.FixedLenSequenceFeature([], tf.float32, default_value=0.0, allow_missing=True)
          }
          parsed_features = tf.parse_single_example(proto, f)
          features = parsed_features["features"]
          label = parsed_features["label"]
          return features, label


   dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(['csv.tfrecords'])
   dataset = dataset.map(_parse_function)
   dataset = dataset.shuffle(10000).repeat().batch(128)
   iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
   features, label = iterator.get_next()
   ```

I ran both the cases `(csv vs tfrecords)` on a randomly generated csv. The total time for 10 batches (128 samples each) for a csv direct read was around `204s`, while that of tfrecord was around `0.22s`.

Comment: I've stumbled upon the link that you've provided in your answer just an hour after I posted the question.Hence, I haven't responded to your answer. Yes, I think your answer does answer the question.