# how to convert csv file to tfrecord

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tfrecord

I am actually working with miniconda and tensorflow and trying to train a model for object detection and I'm facing a problem when running generate_ tfrecord.py to convert csv to tfrecord the error is:

```
"generate_tfrecord.py", line 90, in <module> 
               tf.app.run()
```

I used this link
 https://github.com/datitran/raccoon_dataset/blob/master/generate_tfrecord.py

```
(tensorflow) C:\Users\OctaNet\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\models\research\object_detection>python generate_tfrecord.py --csv_input=images/train.csv  --output_path=data/train.record --image_dir=images/train/


Iterating train
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 90, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "C:\Users\OctaNet\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\platform\app.py", line 125, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 80, in main
    tf_example = create_tf_example(group, path)
  File "generate_tfrecord.py", line 67, in create_tf_example
    'image/object/class/label': dataset_util.int64_list_feature(classes),
  File "C:\Users\OctaNet\Miniconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.6.egg\object_detection\utils\dataset_util.py", line 26, in int64_list_feature
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=value))
TypeError: None has type NoneType, but expected one of: int, long
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tensorflow create a tfrecords file from csv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41402332/tensorflow-create-a-tfrecords-file-from-csv)

Comment: @KaitoEinstein unfortunatly no it doesn't help me